# Regex Hour:Minute (till 31:59)

Tags: .net, regex

I need to identify a hour in a string in a Regex. The rules are the following:

- The hour is in the format of `%m` or `%h:%m` (by `%x` I mean `xx` or `x`);
- The hour should be till `31:59`;
- Should **NOT** pass strings like `000`, `25:545`; `:12`;

So, my actual variant of Regex is (with *ExplicitCapture* option, I verify it [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)):

```
((?<hours>([012]*[0-9])|([3]*[01]))\:)*(?<minutes>[0-5]*[0-9])
```

The problem is that I don't achieve to "limit" this string (**`$`**`myregex`**`^`**, surprisingly, stopped detecting a valid string). Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
^((?<hours>([012]?\d)|(3[01])):)?(?<minutes>[0-5]?\d)$
```

You have some problems with your regex. Mostly, you're using `*` where you shouldn't. This opens the door to many errors. For example, it matches the string `"0010203333333"`.

Comment: with just a little fix (3?[01]) it worked!
why * opens a way to errors, isn't both equivalent to {0,1}?

Comment: Not at all. `*` means zero or more times: {0,∞} ! And you don't need `3?[01]` - 0 and 1 are already covered by `[012]?\d`.

Comment: and `\:` means `[\:]` not just `[:]`?

Comment: `:` has no special meaning in there, so you don't have to escape that with `\:` (it is mostly ignored by regex engines, because people escape all kind of characters anyway). `[123]` means "one of these characters", but '[3]' just means "one of the character 3" - it is redundant for a single character, it is the same as `3`.